# Adding Radio Buttons to Unordered List using Jquery not working as expected

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between these two statements when trying to add a radio button to an li tag using JQuery?

```
var inputText = $("<input />", {"type":"radio", "name":"choices", "value":choices[i],     "text":choices[i]});'

var inputText =$("<li />").html( '<input type="radio" name="choices" value="'+choices[i]+'">' + choices[i] + '</input>');
```

The former does not display any text beside the radio button on the HTML page even though on inspect element the HTML code is correct while the latter displays correctly. I prefer the former syntax because its cleaner but I can not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid for the `input` element to contain text.  If you have a look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) you will see:

> Start tag: required, End tag: **forbidden**

In the first example jquery places the text inside of an input tag, which the browser does not display as it is invalid.  Something like this:

```
<input>text here</input>
```

In the 2nd example, even though you did attempt to make it invalid, it gets converted to this:

```
<input>
text here
```

If you inspect it you will see the text is outside of the input and therefore is displayed.

Really, both approaches are wrong, even though the second technically works, the end tag should be left off:

```
var inputText =$("<li />").html('<input type="radio" name="choices" value="'+choices[i]+'">' + choices[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With James. In addition: if you want to keep the syntax in the first example, I guess you could use:

```
$('<label />').append($("<input />", {"type":"radio", "name":"choices", "value":"foo" }).after('foo'))
```

Which also wraps your input in a nice `label` element which allows you to click on text-label as well.